# Multiple Aliases for Multiple vhosts httpd

Tags: apache, alias, httpd.conf, vhosts, cname

I want **any domain to point a CNAME on my vhosts** for that i use

```
ServerAlias *
```

in my vhosts but it only works with one vhost if I add it in both the CNAME pointed to the second vhost serves the contented from the first vhost.

```
e.g:
1st: files.domain.com CNAME to files.example.com
2nd: r.domain.com CNAME to r.example.com
```

but second one is also serving files.example.com

My **httpd.conf** has these two vhosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/files.example.com
    ServerName files.example.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/files.example.com/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/files.example.com/logs/custom_log common
    <Directory "/var/www/files.example.com">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/r.example.com
    ServerName r.example.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/r.example.com/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/r.example.com/logs/custom_log common
    <Directory "/var/www/r.example.com">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add ServerAlias lines

below `ServerName files.example.com` add `ServerAlias files.domain.com`

and below `ServerName r.example.com` add `ServerAlias r.domain.com`

In your case apache uses files.example.com as default vhost, because it is first one.

Comment: it only works for the given ServerAlias. but I want any domain to point CNAME.

Comment: CNAMEs and Vhosts are totaly separated. Apache dosen't know if you add CNAME to DNS.
you can add *.domain.com CNAME to files.example.com
and then define default vhost first at apache, then others like file.domain.com. Then you get default vhost at all other domains than files.domain.com

Comment: well i have got it working by assigning a separate ip to that vhost and using a * in the ServerAlias. it worked as i expected

Answer (score 4):

This may not be directly related but it could be of help to others: you can actually put many aliases in the same virtual host entry (in my case for the same domain):

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias mail.example.com files.example.com r.example.com
```

And be sure to include all these as server-aliases also while creating an SSL Certificate for the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting a dedicated ip on the vhost where I want the **ServerAlias** to be * and it worked

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.55:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/r.example.com
    ServerName r.example.com
    ServerAlias *
    ErrorLog /var/www/r.example.com/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/r.example.com/logs/custom_log common
    <Directory "/var/www/r.example.com">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```